# What time of the year do government agencies in the United States typically hand out funding?

Tags: research-process, funding, united-states, postdocs

Are there any specific seasons, months, weeks which have shown to be the time at which the majority of funding is handed out by Government agencies in the US? Are there any reliable studies that have answered questions around this topic in the past?

Comment: @BrianBack - that's still probably too vague to answer; some agencies have year-to-year funding (and so don't know how much they have until Congress passes some form of spending bill) while others have guaranteed amounts every year, regardless of Congress's (in)ability to pass such bills. If you could narrow it down even a bit further it would likely help.

Comment: Fellowships and summer activities certainly have typical yearly deadlines, but do you just want to know about specific research grants of thy kind that professors and lab groups/institutions apply for? The NSF, DoD, and NIH are just a small selection of government agencies in the US, as such a huge amount of funding is federal. The NSF for instance lists year round.

Comment: Many programs at the NSF have application deadlines on a specific yearly (or twice yearly) schedule, with awards coming out about 6 months later.  However, these are spread around the year, so there's no one time of year that's applicable to all areas of research.

Comment: I'm curious why you want to know? Most people only care about proposal deadlines for their particular field, which as others have already pointed out, can be spread out over the entire year.

Answer (score 2):

The agencies I'm familiar with (NIH) have published review cycles, and list not only the submission dates, but the approximate dates of first disbursement. Failing this, an email to a program coordinator will probably get you the info you need.  Also, many institutions have grants coordinators whose job it is to know exactly this information (since it accounts for a large proportion of a departments' income). See if you have access to one